# @PrimaryKey of Room Table creates an unexpected behaviour in Android Paging

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-paging

I am implementing `Paging` with cache using `Room` database by following this codelab tutorial : - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#13

However while implementing the caching part, I have come across some strange behaviour while appending the next page in `recyclerview`.

The `RemoteMediator` only fetches the 2nd page data in a continuous infinite loop. Rather than fetching data for the next page it continuously fetches data for the 2nd page.

I have found out that this is happening because of @PrimaryKey of table. I have `Int` as @PrimaryKey in the table and it is 5 characters long.

The same is implemented in the codelab tutorial, where they also have `Int` as @PrimaryKey. But they have a minimum 7 character long randomized primary key. And it works perfectly fine. To verify this, I have made my @PrimaryKey around 15 character long by adding

```
id = id + System.currentTimeMillis()
```

and after doing this it works perfectly. But in real scenario I can't modify the id.

So, is there any limitations in @PrimayKey of Room table(i.e. like the primary key must have minimum 7 character)? Or is @PrimaryKey have to be randomize in Room? Or I am doing something wrong here?

Here is the code and JSON.

**JSON FORMAT**

```
[
    { 
        "id": 24087,
        "date": "2020-07-15T11:20:00",
        "link": "https://www.somesite.com/24534-eu-covid-19-stimulus-negotiations-and-its-historic-backdrop-2020-07-21/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "EU Covid-19 Stimulus Negotiations And Its Historic Backdrop"
        },
        "excerpt": {
            "rendered": "After a long debate between the opposing factions, the European Union agreed on a recovery fund to aid the economy amidst the Covid-19 pandemic..."
        }
    },
    {..},
    {..}
]
```

**Story.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "stories")
data class Story(
    @PrimaryKey @field:SerializedName("id") var storyId: Long,
    @field:SerializedName("date") val date: String,
    @field:SerializedName("link") val link: String,
    @Embedded(prefix = "title_") @field:SerializedName("title") val title: Title,
    @Embedded(prefix = "excerpt_") @field:SerializedName("excerpt") val excerpt: Excerpt    
)

data class Title(
    val rendered: String
)

data class Excerpt(
    val rendered: String
)
```

**RemoteMediator.kt**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class StoryRemoteMediator(
    private val category: Int,
    private val ocapiDatabase: OCAPIDatabase
) : RemoteMediator<Int, Story>() {

    private val storyService = StoryService.create()

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, Story>
    ): MediatorResult {
        val page = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeysClosestToCurrentPosition(state)
                remoteKeys?.nextKey?.minus(1) ?: STORY_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
            }
            LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeysForFirstItem(state) ?: 
                    throw InvalidObjectException("Remote key and the prevKey should not be null")

                remoteKeys.prevKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
            }
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeysForLastItem(state) ?:
                    throw InvalidObjectException("Remote key should not be null for $loadType")

                remoteKeys.nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
            }
        }

        try {
            val stories = storyService.getStories(page = page, category = category)

            val endOfPaginationReached = stories.isEmpty()

            ocapiDatabase.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH && stories.isNotEmpty()) {
                    ocapiDatabase.storyDao().deleteAll()
                    ocapiDatabase.storyRemoteKeysDao().deleteAll()
                }
 
                val prevKey = if (page == STORY_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1
                val nextKey = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else page + 1

                val keys = stories.map {
                    StoryRemoteKeys(
                        storyId = it.storyId,
                        prevKey = prevKey,
                        nextKey = nextKey
                    )
                }
                ocapiDatabase.storyDao().insertAll(stories)
                ocapiDatabase.storyRemoteKeysDao().insertAll(keys)
            }

            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPaginationReached)
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }


    private suspend fun getRemoteKeysClosestToCurrentPosition(state: PagingState<Int, Story>): StoryRemoteKeys? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { position ->
            state.closestItemToPosition(position)?.storyId?.let { storyId ->
                ocapiDatabase.storyRemoteKeysDao().getRemoteKeysById(storyId)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeysForFirstItem(state: PagingState<Int, Story>): StoryRemoteKeys? {
        return state.pages.firstOrNull { it.data.isNotEmpty() }?.data?.firstOrNull()
            ?.let { story ->
                ocapiDatabase.storyRemoteKeysDao().getRemoteKeysById(story.storyId)
            }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeysForLastItem(state: PagingState<Int, Story>): StoryRemoteKeys? {
        return state.pages.lastOrNull { it.data.isNotEmpty() }?.data?.lastOrNull()
            ?.let { story ->
                ocapiDatabase.storyRemoteKeysDao().getRemoteKeysById(story.storyId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it more clear, here is the log which prints the the current page number to fetch from network.

```
2020-07-22 18:21:35.767 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:36.599 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:37.517 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:38.456 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:39.723 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:40.459 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:41.275 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:42.191 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:43.095 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:44.010 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
2020-07-22 18:21:44.903 3510-3510/com.milan.ocapi I/STORY_PAGE: 2
```

As you can see it does not fetch next(i.e. 3, 4, 5) page. It goes into loop.
For testing, I have also changed @PrimaryKey to link(which is String type value), and it is working in that condition also.

So I am pretty sure that there is something wrong with @PrimaryKey length.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly - there is no such limitation for character length of keys in Paging.

The reason that you are loading the same page over and over again in `RemoteMediator` is due to Paging being unable to tell you've hit the last page through `endOfPaginationReached`, but is receiving invalidations telling it the data has updates, and so it should try to load again.

Check that `stories.isEmpty()` is `true` after loading the second page and if so, try returning immediately with `return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)`?

Also, check to see if `PagingSource` is being invalidated somehow although you're fetching the same page. Does writing the same items somehow trigger invalidation or update a column even though it's technically keyed on the same page, perhaps the date field is changing each time you make the request?

Comment: Ok. I'll try to check `stories.isEmpty()` is `true` or `not`. But can you explain me, why it's working perfectly with `link`(type of string) as Primary Key?. The data is same in both conditions.